# Необходимо заполнить двумерный массив значениями от 1 до 25 по схеме. C++

Tags: c, массивы

Необходимо заполнить двумерный массив значениями от 1 до 25 по следующей схеме [image: введите сюда описание изображения] 
и вывести полученную матрицу на консоль. В общем это лабораторная работа, которую я почти смог сделать, но возникла проблема. Я не знаю как сделать правильный порядок значений (у меня вышло немного не то). Это то что я смог накодить, но это не правильно.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
int main() 
{
    int Arr[5][5]; 
    int k = 1; 
    int i, j; 
    for (i = 4; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 5; j++) 
        {
            Arr[i][j] = k; 
            k++; 
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) 
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 5; j++) 
        {
            printf("%2i ", Arr[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\r\n"); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Если код на С, почему метка С++?

Answer (score 1):

Самый простой вариант

```
for (int i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < n; ++j)
    {
        int ij = j;

        if(i % 2 == 1)
        {
            ij = n - ij - 1;
        }

        Arr[i][ij] = k++;
    }
}
```